# Mongoid saving date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime, mongoid

I have a **Person** model :

```
class Person

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes  

  field :dob, :type => Date  

end
```

I'm getting my `date` values as strings from a csv file:

> "1990-10-23"

How do I save them in db?

I tried

> Date.parse(""1990-10-23")

But it gives `Invalid date` error.

Comment: what versions are you using? Did your error raise when you did Date.parse("1990-10-23") (Please note aswell the typo in your question => ""1990-10-23") or when you tried to create a Person? I mean, the error is related with mongoid or with rails-ruby? I've tried your example and it works in my computer (ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.0 and mongoid 3.1.5)

Comment: In console it works fine. But when I create a new Person from data in a csv file it throws error. `Date.parse()` works fine in console.

Comment: Thus, probably the error is in you csv file. Which line fails? what is the value of the field with the date in that csv row?

Comment: Nope there's no error in the csv file. It's just that the csv file has date as string in format `1999-2-23`.In console I can do `Date.parse("1999-2-23")`. But when saving a person,if I save the `:dob` as Person.first.dob=`Date.parse("1999-2-23")` it throws an `invalid Date` error.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, It works for me(again in the console). Could you paste the code where the exception raises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the way to go it in rails.

```
"1990-10-23".to_time(:local)
> 1990-10-23 00:00:00 +0530  

"1990-10-23 11:00 PM".to_time(:utc)  
> 1990-10-23 23:00:00 +0530
```

Any other methods are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in your field (an unnecessary colon). What you want is:

```
field :dob, :type => Date
```

Then you'll be able to do things like:

```
Person.create(:dob => Date.new(1981, 1, 1))
```

Types in Mongoid are always classes (not symbols). The full list of supported classes is [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#fields).